# group and sort sqlite records

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table with the following cols

```
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
body TEXT,
category TEXT,
is_readed INTEGER,
date INTEGER
```

i have the records **look the example**

i have the following query

```
SELECT
    _id, body, category, is_readed
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY
    category
ORDER BY
    category, is_readed, date DESC
```

i want show **only the first record** for category (regardless of whether is_readed is 0 or 1) but i want show first (if exist) the record with `is_readed == 1`. but sometimes show first record with `is_readed == 0` even if exist one with `is_readed == 1`

**Note**: I'm using ContentProvider not raw queries

#### Update

after try a while with this roughly work

```
SELECT
    _id, body, category, MIN(is_readed) as is_readed
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY
    category
ORDER BY
    category, date DESC
```

i still are making tests but I'm still not convinced

#### Examples

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY category, is_readed ASC, date DESC;

_id|category|body|is_readed|date
19|Hogar|message1|1|1371449889136
16|Hogar|message2|1|1371449806704
15|Hogar|message2|1|1371449803825
11|Hogar|message3|1|1371448915930
5|Hogar|message4|1|1371447395055
4|Hogar|message4|1|1371447391394
23|Linea blanca|message2|0|1371450430216
26|Linea blanca|message1|1|1371450719124
24|Linea blanca|message4|1|1371450431604
21|Linea blanca|message1|1|1371449893835
20|Linea blanca|message1|1|1371449891488
17|Linea blanca|message3|1|1371449810104
13|Linea blanca|message3|1|1371448994173
12|Linea blanca|message2|1|1371448917864
6|Linea blanca|message4|1|1371447397387
22|Vehiculos|message3|0|1371450428817
14|Vehiculos|message3|0|1371449801144
25|Vehiculos|message4|1|1371450717115
18|Vehiculos|message4|1|1371449887682
10|Vehiculos|message1|1|1371448422563
9|Vehiculos|message4|1|1371448419438
8|Vehiculos|message3|1|1371448416315
7|Vehiculos|message4|1|1371448395644
3|Vehiculos|message3|1|1371447388887
2|Vehiculos|message1|1|1371447386126
1|Vehiculos|message2|1|1371447383557
```

---

#### My Update

```
SELECT
    _id, body, category, MIN(is_readed) as is_readed
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY
    category
ORDER BY
    category, date DESC

_id|category|body|is_readed|date
4|Hogar|message4|1|1371447391394
23|Linea blanca|message2|0|1371450430216
14|Vehiculos|message3|0|1371449801144
```

---

#### @Hoan Nguyen answer

```
4|Hogar|message4|1|1371447391394
6|Linea blanca|message4|1|1371447397387
1|Vehiculos|message2|1|1371447383557
```

---

#### Expected result

```
19|Hogar|message1|1|1371449889136
23|Linea blanca|message2|0|1371450430216
22|Vehiculos|message3|0|1371450428817
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to implement raw queries in my ContentProvider and also a subquery, but I think that can be performed without the subquery

```
SELECT
    _id, body, category, is_readed, date
FROM
(
    SELECT
        _id, body, category, is_readed, date
    FROM 
        table
    GROUP BY
        is_readed, category
    ORDER BY
        category ASC, is_readed DESC, date DESC
)
GROUP BY
    category
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    _id, body, category, is_readed
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY
    category
HAVING 
    max (is_readed)
ORDER BY
    category, is_readed, date DESC
```

Comment: i want only the first record by category. Please read the explanation

Comment: Your sentence means to me the first record in the results should have is_readed = 1 if exists and not only one record for each category.